# Retrieving type of Opencv Mat_<T> at compile time

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to access the element type T of an opencv matrix Mat_<\T> at compile time; Is there any way to do it? I am trying to achieve the following:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T& mat) {

  // T::type* ptr = (T::type*)mat.data;
}

foo(Mat_<float>::ones(5,5));
```

The following declaration is not an option:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const Mat_<T>& mat);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a [typedef called value_type](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/616db74e4951842ff0ed88ab724e93f5bd9b3b64/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp#L947) that does what you want.

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T& mat) {
    T::value_type* ptr = ...;
}
```

Comment: Use the source Luke. :-)

Comment: Couldn't find the source either :( , I quickly looked for it as well. They used to have the header within the documentation of Mat_ once, I think they should put it back :)